# How do I change the boundaries of symbols used/detected in Vim omni completion?

Tags: vim, omnicomplete

For example, in Sass I'm using dashes for variable names, and I have a variable called:

```
$hello-there
```

If I type in `he` then attempt to complete it, it will only complete `hello`. How would I make it so that it would complete `hello-there`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it is adding the dash to the [iskeyword](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27iskeyword%27) option. Something like the following:

```
set iskeyword+=-
```

Maybe you could add this setting only to sass files only using the appropriate [filetype](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html#filetype).